# How to retrieve only AS400 Enabled Users using jt400 API

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400, jtopen

is there a possibility to retrieve only the Enabled Users -to add a filter- to the getUsers method of UserList of jt400?

I did the following implementation but it does not have a good performance,
so I am trying to find a better way and if there is a possibility to filter the users and to get only the Enabled users.

```
Set<String> as400Users = new HashSet(); 
AS400 as400 = new AS400(host, username, password);

//Retrieving Users
UserList users = new UserList(as400);
Enumeration io = users.getUsers();

  while (io.hasMoreElements()) {
            com.ibm.as400.access.User u = (com.ibm.as400.access.User)io.nextElement();
            String userName = u.getName();

            if (u.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("*ENABLED")) {
                as400Users.add(userName);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could query the USER_INFO view like this:

```
select * 
from qsys2.user_info
where status = '*ENABLED'
```

This became available at v7.1. Note that this only provides users that you have authority to.

You also might want to move the `getName()` call inside the filter:

```
Set<String> as400Users = new HashSet(); 
AS400 as400 = new AS400(host, username, password);

//Retrieving Users
UserList users = new UserList(as400);
Enumeration io = users.getUsers();

while (io.hasMoreElements()) {
    com.ibm.as400.access.User u = (com.ibm.as400.access.User)io.nextElement();

    if (u.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("*ENABLED")) {
        as400Users.add(u.getName());
    }

}
```

Or you could use the newer `foreach` syntax with `getUsers(-1,0)`

```
Set<String> as400Users = new HashSet(); 
AS400 as400 = new AS400(host, username, password);

//Retrieving Users
UserList users = new UserList(as400);
for (com.ibm.as400.access.User u: users.getUser(-1,0)) {
    if (u.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("*ENABLED")) {
        as400Users.add(u.getName());
    }
}
```

Now just choose the fastest method.